# casbah_2.12 cannot work with MongoDB 4.0.0

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, casbah

I have a Spark job which reads data from MongoDB, everything is fine when I connect to MongoDB 3.x, But when I upgrade to MongoDB 4.x, runtime error happens.

now my spark & casbah version is as follows(all are of latest version):

- spark-core_2.12:3.0.1
- spark-sql_2.12:3.0.1
- mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.0
- casbah_2.12:3.2.1

but I got errors when running the spark job connecting to MongoDB 4.0.5:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoOptions
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoOptions$.<init>(MongoOptions.scala:40)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoOptions$.<clinit>(MongoOptions.scala)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.BaseImports.$init$(Implicits.scala:154)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$.<init>(Implicits.scala:141)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$.<clinit>(Implicits.scala)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient.apply(MongoClient.scala:218)
```

Seems casbah needs MongoOptions, but this class has been removed from MongoDB 4.x. I noticed the casbah version has not upgraded since Dec 06, 2016, it stays in 3.2.1 for 3 years.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Well, that project has been [deprecated](https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/) for a while, so not surprised it doesn't work with newer scala versions. Why not using the [**Spark** connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) directly?

Comment: "Users are encouraged to migrate to the Mongo Scala Driver"

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your advice. the project has some legacy codes, both casbah & spark connector are used. I am considering using spark connector only.

Comment: yes, thank you for comment @EmiCareOfCell44